# Showing that the set define as follows is subring of its subset that a ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be a ring and two ring homomorphism $f:R \to S$ and $g:R \to S$. Show that $H = \{x \in R | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is subring of R.

My attempt:

Let $x,y \in H$. Then, $f(x)=g(x)$ and $f(y)=g(y)$. Now,

$f(x-y) = f(x)-f(y) = g(x)-g(y) \in H$

and

$f(xy) = f(x)f(y) = g(x)g(y) \in H$

Hence, $H$ is subring of R.

Am I right?

Comment: There are false statements in your "proof": $H$ is a subset of $R$, but  $f(x-y)$ is an element of $S$. Thus, in general, it is impossible that $f(x-y)\in H$. Also, you are not showing everything. For example, to conclude that $x-y\in H$ you need to prove that $f(x-y)=g(x-y)$ and there is not such an equality in your solution. Also, you need to show that $0\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ and $g$ are ring homomorphisms, $f(0_R) = 0_S = f(0_R)$, so, $0_R$ is an element in $R$ for which $f$ and $g$ has the same value, in other words, $0_R \in H$.

Now, take $x$ and $y$ in $H$, that is, $x$ and $y$ are elements of $R$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f(y) = g(y)$. Now, $x-y$ is an element of $R$ such that $$f(x-y) = f(x)-f(y) = g(x)-g(y) = g(x-y),$$ that is, $x-y \in H$. Similarly we can show that $xy \in H$.

Answer (score 0):

$H$ is non empty as $1_R\in R$ , $f(1_R)=1_S=g(1_R).$
Let $x,y \in H$.
$f(x)=g(x),f(y)=g(y)\in H$,
Now,
$f(x)-f(y) = f(x-y)= g(x-y)\in H$
Thus closed under subtraction.
and

$f(x)f(y) = f(xy) = g(xy) \in H$
,closed under multiplication.
Hence, $H$ is subring of R.